# Set theory and relations - Is this relation symmetric, antisymetric or neither?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I have just started learning set theory and need an explanation on how to go about this question:

Is the relation, "$xRy$ if and only if the difference of $x$ and $y$ is $<4$ " symmetric, antisymetric or neither?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Question should identify the kind of thing that $x$ and $y$ are in defining the relation $R$.  Mentions of set theory might suggest that $x$ and $y$ are in this context supposed to be sets, but then the meaning of "the difference of $x$ and $y$ is $\lt 4$" is unclear.  We do not generally subtract sets, but perhaps you have in mind the *size* of the symmetric difference of two sets, or perhaps you have in mind that $x$ and $y$ are numbers of some kind for which subtraction does make literal sense.

Comment: Supposing $x, y \in \mathbb R$, we need to define the "difference between x and y".  Is it defined by $x-y \lt 4?\;\; y-x\lt 4?\;$ or $\;|x-y|\lt 4?  In the first two cases, the relation is not symmetric.  In the third case: the relation is symmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

Try to answer the following question:

- if the difference between $x$ and $y$ is less than $4$, can you say that the difference between $y$ and $x$ is less than $4$?
- if the difference between $x$ and $y$ is less than $4$ and the difference between $y$ and $x$ is less than $4$, can you conclude that $x=y$?

If the answer is yes, give a proof. If not, give a counter example.